# Error while installing chaincode in fabric 2.0

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

when I try to approve chaincode definition for my organization using peer lifecycle chaincode approveformyorg I got this error

> **Error: proposal failed with status: 500 - failed to invoke backing implementation of 'ApproveChaincodeDefinitionForMyOrg': could not
> serialize chaincode parameters to state: could not deserialize
> metadata for namespace namespaces/hei-authorization-contract#1: could
> not query metadata for namespace
> namespaces/hei-authorization-contract#1: GET_STATE failed: transaction
> ID: 85c9a7441cda90c5860c0d64b45e3d0fb3aaf963ccb2b3c0420e517c60880a5a:
> private data matching public hash version is not available. Public
> hash version = {BlockNum: 9, TxNum: 0}, Private data version =**

can someone please explain the cause of this error

I am using the following commands to install chaincode

```
peer lifecycle chaincode package contracts.tar.gz --path /opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode/Contracts/ --lang node --label contracts_0.0.1

peer lifecycle chaincode install contracts.tar.gz

peer lifecycle chaincode queryinstalled >&log.txt

export PACKAGE_ID=$(sed -n "/contracts_0.0.1/{s/^Package ID: //; s/, Label:.*$//; p;}" log.txt)

echo PackageID is ${PACKAGE_ID}

peer lifecycle chaincode approveformyorg -o orderer1.regulator.com:7050  --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/regulator.com/orderers/orderer1.regulator.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.regulator.com-cert.pem --channelID dvchannel --name contracts --version 1 --init-required --package-id ${PACKAGE_ID} --sequence 1

peer lifecycle chaincode querycommitted --channelID dvchannel --name contracts
```

Comment: Please provide the Tutorial you are just going through and which command you executed

Comment: I am using fabric 2.0 and following the official fabric samples first-network tutorial

Comment: Please provide the link and the command you used

Comment: I have edited the question and have  included the commands I used

Comment: Much better, would you please also refer to documentation of the samples? There are several. I can't say which of them you are just going through

Comment: I am following this https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/test-network/scripts/deployCC.sh

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, did you manage to solve it ? if so can you please share the steps